# text-overflow ellipsis on flex child not working

Tags: css, flexbox

I have container with `flex`. I want the middle child will take the entire space so I set it `flex: 1`. So far so good.

The next level is that the middle child has 2 child so I want to set it flex too (If you lost me, just skip to the snippet) and the first child I set ellipsis styles. Now, the ellipsis stops working.

If you will click on the button, you will see that everything good with short text;

Any ideas?

```js
function toggle() {
  var el = document.querySelector('.el');
  el.textContent = el.textContent === 'short' ? 'long long long text' : 'short';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 1px solid
}

.wrapper .child2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}

.el {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}

.child3 {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper>* {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="el">long long long text</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child3">child3</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle ellipsis text</button>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.wrapper .child2`.

Actually, as [Mosh Feu suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45813583/2827823), `min-width: 0` should also work, and does, cross browser, though IE is buggy and need `overflow`

The reason also the `child2` need it, is because it is also a flex item, and flex item's, in this case `min-width`, defaults to `auto`, and won't allow it to be smaller than its content, so by adding `overflow: hidden` (or any value but `visible`), or `min-width: 0`, will let it.

```js
function toggle() {
  var el = document.querySelector('.el');
  el.textContent = el.textContent === 'short' ? 'long long long text' : 'short';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 1px solid
}

.wrapper .child2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}

.el {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.child3 {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper>* {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="el">long long long text</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child3">child3</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle ellipsis text</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want.?

I just put `overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;` to your `.child2`

```js
function toggle() {
  var el = document.querySelector('.el');
  el.textContent = el.textContent === 'short' ? 'long long long text' : 'short';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 1px solid
}

.wrapper .child2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
}

.el {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.child3 {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper>* {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="el">long long long text</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child3">child3</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle ellipsis text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if I set the `min-width: 0` of the middle child (`.child2`) it magically works.

**Update** According @LGSon it doesn't works on IE.

```js
function toggle() {
  var el = document.querySelector('.el');
  el.textContent = el.textContent === 'short' ? 'long long long text' : 'short';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
  border: 1px solid
}

.wrapper .child2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.el {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
}

.child2 {
  background: blue;
}

.child3 {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper>* {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="el">long long long text</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child3">child3</div>
</div>

<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle ellipsis text</button>
```

Comment: Yes, it does similar as my `overflow: hidden`, though this won't work on IE, mine does :)

Comment: Really? Good to know.

Comment: Decide to upvote this as if it weren't for IE, it would be fine too :)

Answer (score -1):

That's because class .el doesn't have a width set. Use the CSS below and it works well:

```
.el {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 3em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I want it will take the width as the flex calculated for it..