# text-overflow: ellipsis not working on nested flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm aware of these posts:

- [Prevent a child element from overflowing its parent in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43809612/prevent-a-child-element-from-overflowing-its-parent-in-flexbox)
- [text-overflow ellipsis on flex child not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813304/text-overflow-ellipsis-on-flex-child-not-working)
- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

No answer from there fixes the issue I have in the code snippet below. Here's the html tree:

- parent flex column

  - child flex row

    - label flex (so I can align text vertically)

The only way I could make it work is by making the label an `inline-block`, but I'd really like to keep the flex.

What I'd already done:

- On the child:

  - Set `white-space: nowrap`
  - Set `min-width: 0`
  - Set `overflow: hidden`
- On the parent

  - Set `min-width: 0`
- Permutate the options above with `flex-grow: 1` and `max-width: 100%`

[image: Screen Capture]

```css
.parent-container {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-container {
  border: 1px solid #ebf0ff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 3.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.label {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<body>
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="item-container">
      <span class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you use `display: flex;` for `.label` ??

Comment: To vertically align the text in my app. The code snippet is just an approximation.

Comment: Good discovery. There's no clear reason why ellipsis works only when `display: flex` is removed from `.label`. The two (oldest) answers below provide fixes, but don't address the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B -- Is it not the fact that _when_ `.label` has `display: flex` then its text node becomes an anonymous flex child, and as such also need e.g. `min-width: 0` to behave? ... and if so, this is a duplicate to the linked posts.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg -- A note, no reason to add properties with their default values, e.g. `flex-flow: row nowrap;` and `align-items: stretch;` Both `row`/`nowrap` and `stretch` is a flex container's default.

Comment: @Michael_B I guess this cover it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55042003/8620333

Comment: and never use flexbox as a container for text, this a bad practise and once you add links or styling tags like `strong` everything will get scrambled, related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903923/8620333

Comment: Many thanks for your help LGSon & Temani, you elucidated the mystery. Re default values - I prefer to be specific about my flex definitions, precisely because I know it's s a powerful tool with a lot of blackbox magic under the good.

Comment: @LGSon, in my testing, I wrapped the text in a `span` element, thus eliminating the anonymous item factor. It still didn't work with `min-width: 0`. That's why I posted my comment. I don't believe this post is a duplicate of those posted.

Comment: @Michael_B -- I hope you added/kept `min-width: 0` on the `.label` as well, as it is also a _flex child_, and when done like that it works just fine when text is wrapped. ... like in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjvfnuhc/

Comment: @LGSon, LOL! That was exactly the problem. [This omission got me again!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57143124/3597276) One day I'll learn to keep the min-width override on all flex containers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `flex` for `.label` and to align, use `align-items: center;` for its parent.

```css
.parent-container {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-container {
  border: 1px solid #ebf0ff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 3.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.label {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<body>
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="item-container">
      <span class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm curious why this isn't possible with flexbox. Is it just that in the code snippet above, the content size is at least the maximum width (for reasons I don't fully grasp yet)?

Comment: the workaround using `min-wdith` is for flex child elements and not the flex parent. Your child element had a flex declaration which was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent-container {
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-container {
  border: 1px solid #ebf0ff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 3.25rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.label {
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<body>
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="item-container">
      <span class="label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Remove:

```
display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
```

If you want it vertically aligned, add `this` to `.label`:

```
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
```

Comment: Amazing, these tricks for `margin` saved the day! But I'm curious why this isn't possible with flexbox. Is it just that in the set up I described above, the content size is at least the maximum width (for reasons I don't fully grasp yet)?

Comment: It's all a bit mysterious, but there are strange overflow results when nesting `flexbox`'s.. so let's attribute it to that. Have a read about another [weird overflow issue](https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-fix-overflow-issues-in-css-flex-layouts/) with `flexbox` - expect the unexpected and be cautious when nesting `flexbox`